# Does android community have visual overview tool showing all popular libraries, classes?

Tags: android, android-resources

Do you know if there is anything similar to this in android?

You can click on any of this, and it will show description, very handy, but do we have this in android?

[image: g]

Comment: What is the source of this map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add dependency from remote Maven repo. This feature is available in Android Studio

As per developer docs

*"When some of your dependencies are available in a remote repository, you do not have to download them and copy them into your project. The Android Studio build system **supports remote Maven dependencies**.*

*Maven is a popular software project management tool that helps organize project dependencies using repositories.
Many popular software libraries and tools are available in public Maven repositories. For these dependencies you only have to specify their Maven coordinates, which uniquely identify each element in a remote repository. "*

[image]